# Does apple allow apps that let users post images to a shared page like a forum?

Tags: ios, iphone, photos

I am looking at developing an app in which users can take a picture from their phone, and it will be uploaded to a forum page where everyone on the app can view it.

Since the user could possibly post offensive images and content, will Apple reject my app because it has the potential for users to post offensive content?

What are the "rules" and "guidelines" behind users being able to post content without filters to a forum page where it can be viewed by other users?

Will Apple accept my app if I make it r18?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few years since I posted just such an app.

I set it as appropriate for all ages, and the app review team contacted me for exactly the reason you mention.

I pointed out to them that the online gallery would be curated, so that I had to approve each picture before it would be available to users.

They allowed it through with that assurance.

Comment: How about if the app is r18, does there still has to be a moderator to approve the photos?

Comment: No moderator necessary, there is nothing to worry about.  For example, there are several popular reddit client apps, tumblr apps, imgur apps, Facebook apps, not to mention internet browsers such as the built-in Safari.  Apple does not try to censor the internet (although they might ask that you put a r18 on there for legal reasons)

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate the advice!